# Can't put WAMP online

Tags: apache, port, wampserver, forwarding

**UPD** Provider's fault

---

I think I have read all the instructions and have done everything I could, but it still doesn't work :(

List of things I have done so far:
in `httpd.conf` file of the Apache server:

```
ServerName 192.168.0.102:8080
...

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require all granted
...
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080
```

Then I have the following result:

```
C:\Users\Sam>netstat -na | find ":8080"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

So, I guess, no firewall interruptions..
Then I have forwarded the thing in my TL-WR842ND router as follows:
In DHCP I set static local IP of `192.168.0.102` to my MAC and forwarded port `8080` to that IP. Then I rebooted the router but the port is still closed. 
I can access WAMP though `localhost:8080`, through `192.168.0.102:8080`, but cannot access remotely through the public IP. I also tried to set DMZ to `192.168.0.102` but that also had no impact. I called my provider and they said that they allow port forwarding and the problem must be on my side. pls help :(

Comment: Found out that my provider is damn liar. My router's default gateway is another subnet router 192.168...

Comment: You **most definitely dont want** you PC in the DMZ. Look up `port forwarding`

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running

Comment: Put Apache back onto port 80. Moving it to port 8080 just makes life more of a pain. If you are behind a router you are quite safe using 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I have a common IP address with multiple other users and I have to pay extra to my provider in order to be able to expose services to the outside. I believe that is called a `non-routable IP address`.

You can read about it [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/40336)